# What does this mean by using 'type'

Tags: haskell

I learned that a `type` synonym is a new name for an existing type. It can be used like

```
type MyChar = Char
```

But what does this usage mean like this?

```
class HasField a where
    type FieldType a :: *
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's an [associated type family](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html#assoc-decl), an extension provided by GHC if you use the pragma

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
```

or pass the parameter `-XTypeFamilies` to *GHC* or *GHCi*.

Basically, it declares a class such that each instance of the class can define individually what the type synonym means. For example:

```
data MyDataType = MyDataConstructor Int

instance HasField MyDataType where
    type FieldType MyDataType = Int
```

Comment: I see now and Thanks! I think maybe it's better to go through the GHC user guide before starting to read some open source code...

Answer (score 2):

All of this is a bit advanced so if you're just getting started with Haskell don't feel like you have to understand this right away.

That said, I'll add a simple example to Ørjan's answer, imagine we defined a class like this:

```
-- | Class for types that can be constructed from a list of items.
class Unfoldable t where
    fromList :: [a] -> t a
```

Now we can define instances for various types:

```
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set

instance Unfoldable [] where
    fromList = id

instance Unfoldable Set where
    fromList = Set.fromList
```

But this has two weaknesses:

- It doesn't work with **monomorphic** types: types that do not have a parameter for their element type.  For example, `ByteString` and `Text` are monomorphic—their element type is hardcoded to `Char8` and `Char` respectively.
- It would be nice to have `fromList :: Ord k = [(k, v)] -> Map k v, but that definition doesn't support it, because`(k, v)`is not a type parameter of`Map`.

So using `TypeFamilies` it's possible to improve it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds #-}

import Data.Monoid
import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Text (Text, pack)
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

class Monoid m => Unfoldable m where
    type Element m :: *
    type Constraint m :: GHC.Exts.Constraint
    type Constraint m = ()

    fromList :: [Element m] -> m

instance Unfoldable [a] where
    type Element [a] = a
    fromList as = as

instance Ord a => Unfoldable (Set a) where
    type Element (Set a) = a
    type Constraint (Set a) = Ord a
    fromList = Set.fromList

instance Ord k => Unfoldable (Map k v) where
    type Element (Map k v) = (k, v)
    type Constraint (Map k v) = Ord k
    fromList = Map.fromList

instance Unfoldable Text where
    type Element Text = Char
    fromList = pack
```

Look at the type of `fromList :: Monoid m => [Element m] -> m`.  Basically, `Element m` is a synonym whose expansion is different for each differenct choice of `m`:

- `Element [a] := a`
- `Element (Map k v) := (k ,v)`
- `Element Text := Char`

The other trick here is the use of `ConstraintKinds` to allow each class instance to require individualized constraints on the type variables (e.g., `Ord k` for `Map`).  That's a topic for another day...

Comment: (1) I see you define the `Constraint` type, but you don't seem to be using it. I guess you want it as a constraint on `fromList`? (2) If you insist on using the clashing name `Constraint`, I think `GHC.Exts` ought to be imported `qualified`, even if this happens to work while defining the instances.